# How to properly use read receipt header in codeigniter emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

i want to get read receipt of emails that we send by codeigniter emails.
i am not able to get how to use it in codeigniter mails.
i know we should use X-confirm reading but its not working in codeigniter.

```
public function formcomplete()
{
        $appid = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $datan = $this->product->fetchtransaction($appid);
        $txnid = $datan[0]['txn_id'];
        $email = $datan[0]['email'];
        $config = array(
                'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
                 'smtp_port' => 587,
                'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
                'smtp_user' => 'user',
                 'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
                'mailtype'  => 'text',
                 'charset'   => 'utf-8',
                 );
    $datanew = array(
            'firstname' => $datan[0]['firstname'],          
    ); 

      $this->email->initialize($config);
      $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->set_crlf("\r\n");
      $subject = "Complete Your Partially Filled Application-".$appid."";
      $data['datan'] = $datanew;
      $mesg = $this->load->view('email/reminder/form_complete',$data,true);
      $this->email->to($email);

     $this->email->AddCustomHeader( "X-Confirm-Reading-To: notifications@mymail.com" );

      $this->email->from('support@mail.com','Company Email');
     $this->email->subject($subject);
     $this->email->message($mesg);
     $this->email->send();
     $baseurl = "https://www.getyourevisa.com/admin/application/view/";
     $completeurl = $baseurl.$appid;
     //redirect('admin/application/view/' . $appid);
     echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.alert('Form Complete Reminder Successfully Sent');
       window.location.replace('$completeurl');
       </script>");


}
```

i have used below line, but its not working, i think there should be some other way to write this code.

```
     $this->email->AddCustomHeader( "X-Confirm-Reading-To: notifications@mymail.com" );
```

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by not working?

Comment: read receipt is not working.

Comment: What do you mean? Does the header not appear in the sent message, or is it there but has no effect? Be aware that support for read receipts is practically nonexistent; it’s entirely up to clients whether they respond to it, but hardly any will.

Comment: no there is no header in sent message, i guess.

Comment: Don’t guess, check, and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

For CI version 3, it should be

```
$this->email->set_header('X-Confirm-Reading-To', 'name@email.com');
```

For CI version 4

```
$email->setHeader('X-Confirm-Reading-To', 'name@email.com');
```